# Цикл while, полученные значения вставить в ячейки

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

В коде есть 2 проблемы:

1) В диапазоне ws['B3:B7'] я должен написать условие(аргумент) **до конца строки/столбца** или **до пустой ячейки** ws['B3:??'] 

2) В цикле While значение полученное **'i'** нужно вставить в указанный диапазон, и так же написать условие(аргумент) **до конца строки/столбца** или **до пустой ячейки** ws['D3:??']

Мой код показывает ошибку -> *builtins.AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'* in line ws['D3:D7'] = i

Я не понимаю почему диапазон указанный в цикле является кортеж и как исправить ошибку?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values))

i = a

while i <= b:
    ws['D3:D7'] = i
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)


wb.save('Test2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Диапазон является кортежем кортежей, поскольку содержит ссылки типа Лист:Ячейка. Вам нужно добраться до свойства `value` этой самой ячейки. Поэтому код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
while i <= b:
    for cell in ws['D3:D7']: #cell - кортеж ссылка, часть кортежа диапазона
        cell[0].value = i    #cell[0] первый элемент кортежа-ссылки на ячейку
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)
```

Мне на совсем понятна цель записи одного и того же значения в диапазон ячеек, но это уже ваша забота.

**UPDATE:** (некрасивый вариант, от слова "колхозить")

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values))
i = a


count = ws.max_row - ws.min_row #подсчитываем количество непустых ячеек в исходном файле
for cell in ws['D3:D10']:
    if not count:
        break                   #прекращаем цикл, если количество итераций исчерпано
    cell[0].value = i
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)
    count -=1
```

Проверяем:

```
for cell in ws['D3:D10']:
    print(cell[0].value)
```

На выходе:

```
1976-01-02
1976-02-02
1976-03-02
1976-04-02
None
None
None
None
```

**UPDATE 2** (нормальный вариант):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values))
i = a


#ниже пишем значения в ячейки. колонка номер 4 - это колонка 'D'
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=ws.min_row, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=4, max_col=4):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = i
        i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)
```

Проверяем:

```
for cell in ws['D3:D10']:
    print(cell[0].value)
```

На выходе:

```
1976-01-02
1976-02-02
1976-03-02
1976-04-02
None
None
None
None
```

**UPDATE 3** - вроде разобрались, что нам нужно получить в итоге:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

values = [row[0].value for row in ws['B3:B7']]
a = datetime.datetime.date(min(values))
b = datetime.datetime.date(max(values))
i = a

row=3
while i <= b:
    ws.cell(row=row, column=4).value = i
    i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)
    row += 1
```

Проверяем:

```
for cell in ws['D3:D3000']:
    print(cell[0].value)
```

Получаем:

```
1976-01-02
1976-02-02
1976-03-02
1976-04-02
...
2018-02-02
2018-03-02
2018-04-02
2018-05-02
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Код изначально сработал не совсем верно, я подвинул `i = i + relativedelta(months = 1)` под `cell` и заработало верно.    Почему одного и того же значения? В диапазоне выбираем **ws['B3:B7']** первую и последнюю дату, например между ними 8 месяцев. Начиная с первого месяца даты нарастают на месяц до последней даты **ws['B3:B7']**.

Comment: Теперь появилась друга ошибка, цикл не останавливается на последней дате если указать диапазон больше чем нужно. И не пишет все месяца если указать диапазон меньше чем нужно. Решения в  `ws['B3:B7']`, как вместо B7 указать значение **до конца** или **до пустой ячейки** ?

Comment: @BenGoodman "Почему одного и того же значения?" - потому что пока вы не внеси инкремент переменной `i` внутрь цикла, у вас  как раз и присваивались одинаковые значения

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Подскажите пожалуйста как указывать диапазон если он заранее не известен? Например начало **D3** а второе значение как писать?

Comment: @BenGoodman это во многом зависит от того, какие данные у вас в исходном файле. Если там только столбик с датами, тогда все просто. вы можете получить из исходного файла значения `ws.min_row` и `ws.max_row` - то есть диапазон заполненных рядов. это и даст вам возможность установить границы цикла.

Comment: Да там только даты. Можете показать кусок кода? я пробовал, но не смог начать цикл с **D3** именно.

Comment: К сожалению код работает неверно. Начинает вставлять даты с первой строки (хотя нудно с третей) и останавливается на 7 строке (хотя должен продолжать пока не закончиться диапазон периода). Не думал что Openpyxl такой не поворотливый. В **VBA** для указания диапазона достаточно написать просто "Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row". И он начнет итерацию с указанной ячейки и продолжит пока не завершится условие. Неужели нету такого простого решения в OpenPyXl?

Comment: @BenGoodman Код работает так, как ему сказали работать ;). Он начинает вставлять с той строки, значение которой равно ws.min_row в исходном файле. Если у вас что-то записано в первой строке исходного файла, то он и будет начинать с нее. Что касается диапазона периода, то в последнем варианте кода он вообще не используется - используется диапазон, соответствующий диапазону исходных данных. Поэтому код нужно переделывать.

Comment: @BenGoodman обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое. @strawdog возможно ли вас найти в соц сетях или как-то писать вам лично?